# How to change the default display in this example of collapsible sections from collapsed to expanded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used the following example to create several sections that collapse and expand within an entry form.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol

However, in this example all the sections are collapsed by default, while I would prefer that upon loading the form all the sections would be expanded and the user could then select to collapse what they do not need.

Can someone please tell me how the code in this example would need to be changed to load by default all the sections expanded instead of collapsed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need to change `max-height:150px`
2. you need to add class `active` to all collapsible or change `content` property of `active:after` and `collpasible:after` and
3. you need to change javascript like below

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  debugger;
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    debugger;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    else{
      content.style.maxHeight = 0 + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Collapse All

```js
function hide() {
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.content'),
        i = 0,
        l = myClasses.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
     if(myClasses[i].style.display === 'none'){
        myClasses[i].style.display = 'block';
      }
      else{
       myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="hide()">Collapse all</button>
```

One Collapse

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.content')

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
  debugger;
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.content'),
      newClass = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible'),
        j = 0,
        l = myClasses.length;

    for (j; j < l; j++) {
       myClasses[j].style.maxHeight = 0 + "px";
        newClass[j].classList.remove("active");
    }  
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    else{
      content.style.maxHeight = 0 + "px";
    }
  });  
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible active">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="hide()">Collapse all</button>
```

**By default one expand**

Comment: Thanks heaps Hiren, I have this now working! One more question, would it be possible to add a, Expand/Collapse All option? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks Hiren, any chances to get some help on adding the Expand/Collapse All option? Another feature I would also be interested in considering is the option to auto collapse the last open section when expanding a new section. Basically this logic would retain open always only one section.

Comment: @AdriCist Updated for Collapse All,Another Option i am trying

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much Hiren, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AdriCist Welcome Mate

Answer (score 1):

1- Expanding them: in `.content` rule, remove `max-height` declaration, so they all start expanded.
2- Reverse the if statement like this:

```
    if (content.style.maxHeight === '0px'){
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    }
```

Styles also need to be handled.

Comment: Thanks heaps Moaaz. That did the trick perfectly!Could I please ask you to explain also what do you mean by Styles also need to be handled? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I think you are referring to inverting the sign + and - . Correct?

Answer (score 1):

The Bottom Code will work for you actually you just had to remove `max-height = 0` from content in CSS and add change `content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";` to `content.style.maxHeight = 0 + "px";` so when you click the tabs it collapse and default open Hope it helps

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo conseqasdddddddddddddddddasdasdadasdasdasdasddddddddddddddduat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {

  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = 0 + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```